# macports - how can I tell if I still need any ports (since going to Leopard)

Tags: macports

Is there a way to tell whether I still need any MacPort ports?  (besides deleting them of course)

Many port I installed a couple of years back and in the meantime I've gone to SnowLeopard...

Also, in some of my gem installs I'm seeing things like "ld: in /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file is not of required architecture"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed Macports under Leopard then upgraded the OS I would suggest that you delete Macports as Macports does not support upgradinging the OS see [Macports migration notes](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `port dependents` command to check to see which ports depend on a particular port. For example, `$ port dependents $PORT` will show a list of all ports that require `$PORT`.